# Prepaid and Postpaid in a single Paypal Payment Transaction

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment

I need to integrate two types of payment in a single transaction with paypal.

Can anyone give me an idea on how to get over with this? I'm really stuck in the situation where my customers wants to buy some of my services, and pay via paypal credit cart, and then wants to add some item which will postpaid?

Will this be doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal orders through Express Checkout will be your best option for adding additonal items to the order after it has been placed.

An order payment action represents an agreement to pay one or more authorized amounts up
to the specified total over a maximum of 29 days.
To set up an order, specify the following payment action in your SetExpressCheckout and
DoExpressCheckoutPayment requests:

PAYMENTREQUEST_n_PAYMENTACTION=Order

An order enables you to create multiple authorizations over the 29 days; each authorization
you create places the buyer’s funds on hold for up to three days. You can capture multiple
payments for each authorization, up to 115% of, or USD $75 more than, the amount you
specify in the DoExpressCheckoutPayment request.

This payment action provides the most flexibility and should be used when either a sale does
not meet, or one authorization plus one reauthorization, do not meet your needs.

More information available here: https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_expresscheckout_integrationguide.pdf

Comment: thanks for that one! I guess I'm gonna need time for this, since it's my first time working on this one. cheers